# passing reference to function

Tags: c++, function, reference, pass-by-reference

I have a code that does something like following example, and I'm not sure if this is correct because the executable runs as expected.

```
// source.cpp
void compute_x(int& ref)
{
    ref = 0;
}

void f(int x) 
{
    int local = x;
    local = 1;

    if (local)
    {
          return copute_x(local);
    }
    else return;
}

int main()
{
    f(2);
    return 0;
}
```

the code runs but, Is variable `local` valid once `f` returns?

Comment: compute_x does not return a value! your code does not compile.

Comment: sorry, my mistake, I modified my post.

Comment: I should have asked this question another time. need to sleep. I made an edit again. thanks for patience.

Comment: even worse, now `compute_x` and `f` don't return.

Comment: @user1810087 so this is bad? I should have compute x first and then return from `f()`?

Comment: no... but now you can just ignore the `return`s...

Comment: The function `f` calls a function `copute_x`,which is not supplied.

Comment: In function `f`, the variable `local` is assigned the value in `x`, then overidden with the value `1`.  You should probably use `int local = 1;`. Also, get rid of the `x` parameter since it is not used.

Comment: I don't see how the posted code executes because it doesn't compile.

Comment: question: `return copute_x(local)` should be worse than `copute_x(local); return` or is this the same?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews yes I should have checked this, tried to make an example out from my code but obviously it does not compile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `local` goes out of scope after `f` returns.

After your **edit**: but the return value is returned from the function and subsequently returned from `main`.

Comment: I truly apologize, I made an edit again, this time it's exact illustration of my question. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No.the variable local is not valid as its scope is inbetween the braces of the f function defination ...after that It has no existence